# Qt - Keyboard Hook

Tags: qt, keyboard-hook, multiplatform, libqxt

I'm using Qt 5.1.1 and I want make keyboard hooks, but Qtx do not accept my version, but I REALLY need this, for an autoclicker project. Any lib is good to me, but it need to be multiplatform, and what's the best way to "click" in Qt?

Comment: "keyboard hooks"? what exactly do you want to achieve, and what have you tried?

Comment: For example: I just have opened the Qt program and I'll play an game (Qt program focus: background). Then I press F12, and Qt program starts an function, because keyboard hook gets the keyboard events even on background programs.

Comment: There's no API for that in Qt. Window managers usually only deliver input events directed to the specific application (and that's a good thing, thinking about security). You'll need platform-specific code.

Comment: What about "#ifdef WIN32" and something like this for keyboard hook?